# NestedAttributes Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, nested-attributes

I have Events and Songs. When a User logs in they can look at all of their events and that certain event's partycode that were created, click on one and see all the songs for that Event. Now, when the user is not logged in they can add songs to a certain event based on a certain partycode. I am unable to add fields and submit those added fields to the submit button, but I can submit the first set of fields.

new.html.erb(Page that handles selecting an event and adding songs)

```
<br>
<br>
<div class ="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
  <h2> Select an event to add songs to: </h2>
  <%= form_for Song.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:event_id, Event.all, :id, :name) %>
    <h3> Enter your song </h3>
      <%= f.text_field :artist, placeholder: "Artist" %>
      <%= f.text_field :title,  placeholder: "Title" %>
      <%= f.text_field :genre,  placeholder: "Genre" %>

    <h2> Enter the partycode for that event: </h2>
    <%= form_for Event.new do |f| %>
      <h4><%= link_to_add_fields "Want to add more songs click here", f, :songs %></h4>

      <%= f.text_field :partycode %>
      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The link_to_add_fields method is in the application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render("songs_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

The songs_fields partial is defined as follows:

```
<fieldset>
  <%= text_field_tag "songs[][artist]" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "songs[][title]" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "songs[][genre]" %>
</fieldset>
```

Here is my event model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :songs, dependent: :destroy  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :songs, allow_destroy: true

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :partycode, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
end
```

Finally, I have defined a coffeescript file for adding the extra fields:

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_songs', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('event_id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('songs').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

All I want to do is have those extra fields be submitted to my events database which holds the songs. I have posted many questions on this matter but I haven't gotten an answer that was able to fix what I have been looking for, and after spending hours on this code I would really like to find a solution. [image]

Comment: You are creating a `form` inside another `form` which is wrong. Use `nested form` instead. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: Will this fix the multiple submission error that I am having?

Comment: Yes that should probably. Give it a try. The main thing is you can't create a `form` inside another `form`, so you need to fix it anyway.

Comment: Ok. Here is the question that I have been having about that. On the page were I am creating my songs for the certain event I need that events partycode which is only apart of the Event model itself. How would rails check the validity of the partycode the user entered with the partycode that was from the event the user chose in the dropdown menu. I updated my question to show how the page is setup

Comment: That you will need to check in the model/controller wherever you are submitting the form data.

Comment: Thank you. Would I need to define a partycode in the songs model that contained all the partycodes for specific events. That seems like that would eliminate the use of having a second form specifically for events

Comment: I don't know your database structure exactly so that depends on you. But the `partycode` according to me should be saved in the `events` table only and in the `Song` model you can take a `attr_accessor` and then check it against the `event_id` the user has selected from the dropdown.

Comment: Ah that makes sense